# visual studio 2013 on windows xp

Tags: .net-4.0, windows-xp, visual-studio-2013, .net-4.5

Is it possible to run Visual Studio 2013 on Windows XP?

I heard that it is not possible to install .NET Framework 4.5 on Windows XP. What if I want to use Visual Studio 2013 for .NET 4.0 on Windows XP?

Is this possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is not possible. Visual Studio 2013 natively supports .Net v4.5, which does not support Windows XP.

For .Net 4.0 on Windows XP, you may try to use Visual Studio 2010 with .Net 4.0. I am not sure if this will work, but I would suggest you to go for Windows 7 for .Net 4.0 and Windows 8 for .Net 4.5.

Comment: i have installed a fresh copy of windows 7 Ultimate but when ever i tried to install vs 2013 on it i failed? so are you sure it runs on windows 7 ? which version ?

Comment: Hi @AmmarAsjad, I have seen it running successfully on Windows 7 Professional and Ultimate editions. Make sure your copy of Windows and Visual Studio is Genuine ;)

Comment: It is possible to run visual studio with .NET 4.0 on Windows XP.

Comment: I have a genuine, fresh install of Win7HP, just updated but still cannot install VS 2013.

Comment: @John may be you require to install Windows 7 SP1. Not sure of what the issue could be, I found this while Googling - http://stackoverflow.com/q/20516271/1654121. You may check this out too - http://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx

Comment: .NET 4.5 supports Windows Vista SP2 and Windows Server 2008.

Answer (score 4):

It is not possible. Even Visual Studio 2012 requires Windows 7.

However you can still develop applications for Windows XP when targeting .NET 4.0 (or older). With Visual Studio 2013 you can develop applications from .NET 2.0 upwards.

.NET 4.5 requires at least Windows Vista to run. As .NET 4.5 replaces .NET 4.0 (it's not a side-by-side installation as previous .NET versions), you might have some incompatibilty problems if you target .NET 4.0. See this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11127734/development-for-net-4-0-windows-xp-with-visual-studio-2012) for more information.

Comment: I did not find a confirmation that VS 2012 requires Windows 7.

Comment: @PaulK. That might be difficult now to confirm, as VS2012 and Windows 7 are out of support for a while now. I don't think this is still relevant.

Answer (score 3):

As others have said, it's not possible to install Visual Studio 2012 or 2013 on Windows XP. However if you really need .NET 4.5 features on Windows XP install [Mono 3](http://www.mono-project.com/) and use [MonoDevelop](http://monodevelop.com/Download).

Answer (score 0):

You cannot install required runtime, so you cannot install Visual Studio 2013. But you are always free to use a virtual machine. Install it on VM and run VM on XP.

Answer (score 0):

.NET 4.5 requires Windows Vista SP2, Server 2008 or newer.