# Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate won't install Windows 7 SP1

Tags: visual-studio, windows-7, visual-studio-2013

I want to install Visual studio 2013 Ultimate, but an error message pops up saying:

> You need a newer version of windows

After a little research about the known installation issues for VS2013, I updated to SP1 from the Microsoft website and installed IE10, but I am still unable to install it.

Comment: Maybe this can help you?

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516271/install-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-7

Comment: Thank you @robindorbell, but i have the Ultimate edition and it is available for Win 7 Sp1 unlike the Express edition, it is available only for Win 8, ...

Comment: If you right click on computer and select properties, does it say that SP1 is installed?  Sounds totally wrong but on some machines, I've had to install SP1 twice before it registers.

Comment: @cup Yes absolutely, it says SP1 is installed ...

Comment: Could it be the version of .net framework?  Try installing 4.5.1 first.

Comment: @cup, in fact i already have the .NET FW 4.5.1 installed, but i had downloaded it again and install it, but still the same problem ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION FOUNDED:

I have found the solution to my problem, simply by changing the Visual Studio installation File from the C (system drive) it was in the desktop, to the D (other stuff drive) and relaunching the installation again, magically the installation begins without any issues.