# Install Visual studio 2013 Error in Windows 7

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2013

I am trying to install visual studio 2013 express in Windows 7(Home premium) Laptop and it gives me the following error message and don't let me install this.

[image]

I found in the following [LINK](http://www.visualstudio.com/products/visual-studio-express-vs) that describes the minimum reqirements to install and all fine in my laptop.

Following is the breif details of my environment and wonder what the problem is.

[image]

If anyone have had the same issue and know how to install this like to hear. Thanks.

Comment: Update your OS with the service Pack, will resolve the issue I think

Comment: Hi Thanks. Yes, I have updated to service pack 1. Shows in the Sceenshot.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Install Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516271/install-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-7)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the screenshot, you're installing `Express 2013 for Windows` instead of `Express 2013 for Web` or 
`Express 2013 for Windows Desktop`. If so, only Windows 8.1 is supported.

Install `Express 2013 for Web` if you just want some general programming.