# Cannot install Visual Studio 2013 Windows Desktop on Windows 7, with win7SP1

Tags: windows

The problem here is that I cannot install the 2013 desktop version even though I have Win7 SPI..
What might be the problem?

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Install Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516271/install-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-7)

Comment: Please transcribe the error message in your Question rather than posting a screenshot.

Comment: Not a duplicate as he was trying to install the Windows 8 version, im installing the one specifically for win7, + My error is exactly my title.