# How to install Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 4 or 5 for Windows 7

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

This is similar to [Install Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516271/install-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-7)

But there are a few key differences:

1. I'd like to install the community edition of Visual Studio 2013, not the express edition.
2. This is a specific question for Update 5. A while back I was able to download Visual Studio 2013 Update 3 for **Windows Desktop** and it worked fine. But despite a lot of searching, I was only able to find a **Windows** [8 or 10] installer for Update 5.

LATE EDIT: the computer I'm referring to in point #2 that worked with visual studio 2013 update 3 is not the computer I'm working on now, it turns out that the computer I'm on now didn't have SP1 installed on it.

At first I thought they merged the installers for windows and windows desktop like they did for VS 2015, but when the download finally finished (much to my disappointment) it presented me with a message saying that it was not compatible with windows 7. I wasn't able to find any official news from microsoft saying they were dropping desktop support for update 5, either.

I think this was a problem with update 4, too.

Has anybody successfully installed Visual Studio 2013 Community Update 5 on Windows 7, using a fresh install?

If not, does anybody know where I can still get an iso for VS 2013 Community Update 3?

It seems like everything that used to be a requirements page for VS2013 redirects to a download page for VS2015 now. I'm not having much luck with archive.org, either.

I found this page about VS 2013 compatibility but it does not say anything about the community edition.
https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/products/visual-studio-2013-compatibility-vs.aspx

Comment: Did you try some alternative like [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) ?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch that is not an option, I use this for more than just C/C++ projects.

Comment: You might install Linux. It has a lot of programming languages implementations...

Comment: Just out of interest, why don't you want to upgrade to Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I love linux, but I have programs already in development for Visual Studio, and they need to stay on VS

Comment: @cybermonkey I tried VS2015 briefly a while ago but for some reason it would not activate, I'll try it again if all else fails, but I'd still really like to know why VS 2013 stopped working with update 5. I'm contributing to a project that currently uses VS 2013 and I'd rather not tell them to update unless it's necessary.

Comment: I'm flagging to close this question as it is user error (user not reviewing the system requirements shown to them before installing). This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem before posting.

Comment: I support the flag to close, I didn't notice it until now but there is a "latest service pack" requirement for all operating systems on a footnote attached to the header of the compatibility list table for Visual Studio 2015 https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs , see screenshot http://imgur.com/k4UM9Dw

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem, when I installed the OS on this machine I didn't realize that I had a Vanilla Windows 7 disk, instead of one that came with Service Pack 1 pre-installed.

I was comparing my experience with 2013 on a different computer that had SP1 already installed, that's why I thought it was due to update 4 & 5, sorry for the mixup!

It appears that Visual Studio 2013 requires **Windows 7 SP1** and higher. When I installed SP1 the Visual Studio 2013 Update 5 installer worked as expected. Visual Studio 2013 did not stop working on Windows 7 after update 3. Also, there's a single iso for all OSes now (as opposed to having one for Windows 8+ and one for Windows 7 in Update 3).

It might be worth noting that Microsoft's Visual Studio 2015 compatibility page shows support for "Windows 7", farther down the page in a footnote it says that it requires "the latest service pack for all operating systems". Unfortunately, I just noticed that footnote now.

https://www.visualstudio.com/visual-studio-2015-compatibility-vs