# Visual Studio 2013 Express for Desktop Installation : Install Button doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2013, installation

I know it may seem like this is a duplicate, like for instance [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516271/install-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-7). But not exactly.

I'm trying to install **VS Express 2013 for Windows Desktop** on Windows 7 (not pro). According to the link above this version of VS Express 2013 is compatible with Windows 7. And I managed to install Visual Studio 2015 Community on the same computer so I don't see why it shouldn't work (why I want VS 2013 when I have 2015 is a long story that doesn't really matter).

Anyway when I download the link from [here](https://www.visualstudio.com/fr-fr/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.aspx) and launch it this page appears and everything seems fine but when I click the Install Button nothing happens.

[image: The problem]

I know they say I "may need to free some space" but on G:\ I've still got 50 Go free and according to them the weight max of that version of VS is 6 Go.

What do you think might be the cause of this problem?

Comment: How much space do you have free on ``C:\``? Much of Visual Studio these days must be installed on ``C:\`` no matter what drive you pick in this dialog. Also, you should really look at using VS 2013 or VS 2015 Community editions which is far more full-featured than the Express editions.

Comment: Aha that may be the problem, only 5,27 Gb. And thanks for the advice.