# Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop Setup Blocked

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, visual-studio-express

I need someone's help. I'm trying to install Visual Studio Express 2013 for Windows Desktop with update 4.

But I got an error:

> Setup blocked
>   -To learn more, you can review the list of common issues and workarounds or examine the log file.

See below:

[image: Installation error]

How do I resolve this?

OS: Windows 7 SP1

Comment: Welcome to SO! Always check to see if SO may have a similar question before posting your own. It's quite probable with a widely used piece of software, someone has already asked a similar question. See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20516271/install-visual-studio-2013-on-windows-7