# Share TaskScheduler instance amongst several tasks

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I created a **TaskScheduler** and i am **passing** it as an argument **across two different tasks.**

Is there any problem in doing it?
Should i be creating a new TaskScheduler instance for each task?

Here's the sample example (actual code inside each task removed for sake of simplicity)

```
var uiSch = System.Threading.Tasks.TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();

var t1 = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Carrier>>(() =>
                    {
                        //does stuff
                    })
                    .ContinueWith(previous =>
                        {
                            //does stuff
                        },
                        System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                        uiSch);

var t2 = Task.Factory.StartNew<List<Logic.WarehouseLogic.Warehouse>>(() =>
                    {
                        //does stuff
                    })
                    .ContinueWith(previous =>
                        {
                            //does stuff
                        },
                        System.Threading.CancellationToken.None,
                        TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnRanToCompletion,
                        uiSch);
```

> [EDIT1]

My question was partially related to the following error:
'The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as a TaskScheduler'
A fix can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659257/how-can-synchronizationcontext-current-of-the-main-thread-become-null-in-a-windo)

Answer (score 5):

There is no problem scheduling multiple tasks on the same task scheduler.