# Hooked events Outlook VSTO continuing job on main Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I have developed an Outlook VSTO addin. Some tasks should be made on a background thread. Typically, checking something in my local db or invoking a web request. After reading several posts, I dropped the idea of calling the Outlook Object Model (OOM) in a background thread.

I have some wpf controls and I successfully managed to use the .NET 40 TPL to perform the async task and when completed to "finish" the job (i.e. accessing the UI or the OOM) in the Main VSTA Thread.

To do so I use a syntax of the form:

```
Task<SomeResult> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
    //Do long tasks that have nothing to do with UI or OOM
    return SomeResult();
});

//now I need to access the OOM
task.ContinueWith((Task<SomeResult> tsk) =>{
   //Do something clever using SomeResult that uses the OOM
},TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
```

So far so good. But now I want to do something similar when hooking an event in the OOM where there are no Form/WPF control. Precisely, my problem comes from the fact that *TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()* throws an exception.

For instance,

```
Items inboxItems = ...;
inboxItems.ItemAdd += AddNewInboxItems;

private void AddNewInboxItems(object item)
{
    Task<SomeResult> task = Task.Factory.StartNew(()=>{
    //Do long tasks that have nothing to do with OOM
    return SomeResult()});


   var scheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
   /* Ouch TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() throws an  InvalidOperationException, 'The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as    a TaskScheduler.' */
   task.ContinueWith((Task<SomeResult> tsk) =>{
       //Do something clever using SomeResult that uses the OOM
   }),scheduler};
}
```

> /* Ouch TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext() throws an  InvalidOperationException, 'The current SynchronizationContext may not be used as    a TaskScheduler.' */

Note that I tried to create a TaskScheduler in addin initialization and putting it in a singleton as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4659257/how-can-synchronizationcontext-current-of-the-main-thread-become-null-in-a-windo). But it does not work, the continuation task is not performed in the desired VSTA Main thread but another one (inspected with VisualStudio).

Any idea ?

Comment: Have you tried async/await?

Comment: No I have not because I am targeting .NET40. Upgrading to .NET45 is not an option for now. However, you are right, I will give a try, this may bring some insights for a fix in 40.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko unfortunately after the *await* keyword the thread that is performing the rest of the task is not the main VSTA thread.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko see the breakpoints that I have set in my code [1](https://goo.gl/xNfFPA) [2](https://goo.gl/S7ypZd) [3](https://goo.gl/Zs4uv7)

Comment: Please show your async/await code.

Comment: You can see a glimpse in the screeshots abover but here is a standalone reproduction case [on a github project](https://github.com/bpatra/Hookmainthread)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is known bug that SynchronizationContext.Current might be null in several places where it should not (including office add-ins). That bug was fixed in .NET 4.5. But since you cannot upgrade to .NET 4.5, you have to find a workaround. As a suggestion, try to do:

```
System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext());
```

when initializing your addon.

Comment: Hi, the SynchronizationContext.Current is null in both .NET 4.0 and .NET 4.5. However, your solution using WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext works. I'll grant you the bounty. Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [SynchronizationContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext(v=vs.110).aspx) class which provides the basic functionality for propagating a synchronization context in various synchronization models. The [Post](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.post(v=vs.110).aspx) method dispatches an asynchronous message to a synchronization context, i.e. the Post method starts an asynchronous request to post a message. See [Using SynchronizationContext for sending events back to the UI for WinForms or WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949789/using-synchronizationcontext-for-sending-events-back-to-the-ui-for-winforms-or-w) for more information and sample code.

FYI The [Current](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.current(v=vs.110).aspx) property allows to get  the synchronization context for the current thread. This property is useful for propagating a synchronization context from one thread to another.

Comment: thks, but I do not get your suggestion. SynchronizationContext.Current is null in my case. If I try to create a new one and use it to create a TaskScheduler instance like this:
    SynchronizationContext context = new SynchronizationContext();
    SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(context);
    TaskScheduler taskScheduler =    TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
It will not work either: the job is not executed in the Main thread. In addition, I do not have a dispatcher, there is no winform/WPF application only some controls (and not in this case).

Comment: It is null when you call it on secondary threads. Try to get it on the main thread.

Comment: Sorry, it's not. It is null on the main thread, see the [screenshot](https://keluro-my.sharepoint.com/personal/bpatra_keluro_com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?guestaccesstoken=CjzPoV%2fA3XWbJ1wdvcnqe98weA1z7vLtKT7eXxtgfUo%3d&docid=0398a764bb29d423692c4c133a3664e9d)